# Is / in memory? AWS/EC2 Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, memory-usage

I've been investigating this for a while, and I'm really confused.

I have an AWS/EC2 m3.medium instance running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-d05e75b8.

I ran into a problem where writing large temporary files to `/tmp` caused the instance to run out of memory. After further investigation, it appears the problem is not limited to `/tmp`.

This is causing the instance to reboot because I have `min-memory` set in watchdog.conf.

I can replicate the problem by doing this:

```
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree
MemFree:         3543808 kB
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# dd if=/dev/zero of=/deleteme bs=10000 count=100000
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
1000000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 5.71321 s, 175 MB/s
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree
MemFree:         2537896 kB
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# sync
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree
MemFree:         2537812 kB
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# rm /deleteme
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree
MemFree:         3541040 kB
```

Here's what mount says:

```
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,discard)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

And fstab:

```
root@ip-172-31-3-68:/# cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
```

What's going on here? Why are my files being stored in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured it out. `MemFree` from `/proc/meminfo` measures the amount of unused memory on the system, without distinguishing by type. This is exactly the same thing that the watchdog daemon looks at when `min-memory` is set in `watchdog.conf`. When writing to a file, the OS page cache holds the data I'm writing in case it needs to be used again. Memory in the page cache is evictable, but the watchdog daemon doesn't care. All it cares about is the unused memory.

This basically means that I can't use `min-memory` in `watchdog.conf`, which is disappointing.